# How to install local rpms according to package dependencies

Tags: local, rpm, yum

I want to do yum update without network.

Two stages:

Step One, download packages on network-connected machine:

```
yum update --downloadonly --downloaddir=/local-dir
```

Step Two, install downloaded packages on non-network machine:

```
rpm -ivh /local-dir/*
```

But step two will failed with error, there failed dependencies does exist in `/local-dir`, but rpm does not detect it automatically.

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        selinux-policy < 3.13.1-89 conflicts with firewalld-0.4.3.2-8.1.el7_3.3.noarch
        NetworkManager < 1:1.4.0-3.el7 conflicts with firewalld-0.4.3.2-8.1.el7_3.3.noarch
        firewalld < 0.3.13 conflicts with firewalld-filesystem-0.4.3.2-8.1.el7_3.3.noarch
        systemd < 219-20 conflicts with libselinux-2.5-6.el7.x86_64
        selinux-policy-base < 3.13.1-66 conflicts with libsemanage-2.5-5.1.el7_3.x86_64
        selinux-policy < 3.13.1-92 conflicts with openssh-6.6.1p1-35.el7_3.x86_64
        firewalld < 0.3.14 conflicts with python-firewall-0.4.3.2-8.1.el7_3.3.noarch
```

Comment: Do you really want to install all the RPM's you downloaded?  Probably not.  You might want to consider creating a local YUM repo.  You'll need to install `createrepo` and you can google the rest.

Comment: No, my raw target is `I want to do yum update without network`, I think `createrepo` is a better way to archive my goal. many thanks @RedCricket

Answer (score 0):

Use `rpm -Uvvh /local-dir/*`

```
 {-U|-upgrade} This  upgrades  or  installs  the  package  currently installed 
  to a newer version.  This is the same as install, 
  except all other version(s) of the package are
  removed after the new package is installed.
```